# How to find the most frequently occurring value in SSRS tablix dataset?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, aggregate-functions

Consider following dataset that is displayed in tablix in SSRS report:

```
GroupID  | ProductID
---------------------
Group 1  | Product1
Group 2  | Product10
Group 1  | Product2
Group 3  | Product27
Group 2  | Product12
Group 2  | Product14
```

I added new row via Insert Row/Outside Group - Below.

On this row I display total number of rows - achieved via CountRows(), number of distinct Groups - achieved via =CountDistinct(Fields!GroupID.Value)

I also want to display the name of the group with the most number of rows, in this case it would be "Group 2" (in case if there is more than one group with the same number of rows I only need to display one of them).

How can this be achieved? I think I should use some of aggregate or lookup functions but so far can't figure out how.

**PS** This report is being ported from Crystal Reports to SSRS. In Crystal Reports this is easily achieved via "Nth most frequent" summary with N=1 but there is nothing like this in SSRS as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a tablix and set `GroupId` as Row Group.

[image]

For Rows Count use:

```
=Count(Fields!GroupID.Value)
```

Right click `GroupID` group in the Row Groups pane and go to group properties, in the Filters tab use the following settings:

[image]

For `Expression` use:

```
=Count(Fields!GroupID.Value)
```

It will filter the top 1 group with the greatest Rows count. The result is something like this:

[image]

**UPDATE:** The previous solution doesn't work if there is more than one group with the same number of occurencies.

Add a tablix, delete the details (default group) and add the GroupID field in the first column.

[image]

For the Rows Count column use the following expression replacing `DataSetName` by the actual name of your dataset:

```
 =LookupSet(
     Fields!GroupID.Value,
     Fields!GroupID.Value,
     Fields!GroupID.Value,
     "DataSetName"
 ).Length
```

Right click your tablix and go to tablix properties, in the `Sorting` tab select `Z to A` order and use the previous expression in the `Sort By` textbox.

[image]

It should show the only one group even if a second group with same number of occurencies is present.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes, this helps, and you don't even need "Rows Count" column in new tablix. However, if you have another group with 3 items (say "Group 1" also has 3 items in this dataset) new tablix will have 2 rows - "Group 1" and "Group 2" and I only want to see one. I tried to use RowNumber() function but it is not allowed in the filter.

Comment: I decided to use your first suggestion and show multiple groups because this seems to be more appropriate solution.